# Should the tag "Verse" be merged with "Poetry"?

Tags: discussion, tag-synonyms

A verse would come to mean a poetic composition, right? In that light we could perhaps merge [verse](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/verse) and [poetry](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/poetry)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[verse](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/verse) *should* probably be made a tag synonym of [poetry](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/poetry). There are currently only two questions tagged with [verse](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/verse) one of which is also tagged with [poetry](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/poetry).

It is probably also difficult to correctly use [verse](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/verse); it is somewhat similar to [technique](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/technique) (or perhaps more accurately, 'mechanics'--which does not seem to be a tag) in being somewhat vague.

(Technically, I feel 'verse' should refer to the technical aspect, the 'mechanics' such as meter and rhyme. The wiki summary for [poetry](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/poetry) has "including poetry formatting and technique"; while mechanics are only a part of technique [which would also include imagery, sound-associations, and word play], it may be best not to make a separation.)

Comment: So...someone ready to propose the synonym?